# Getting String Instead of array from ajax output

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting the string format instead of array format which is outputted from ajax

```
$.get('ajax/order_details.php?order_limit=true&order_limit_id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>', function(data){
                                alert(data.toSource());
```

});

And this is the code which i am using it in php file (order_details.php)

```
if(isset($_GET['order_limit_id']) and isset($_GET['order_limit'])){
    $g_o = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM ocreturn r, ocorder o WHERE o.order_id = '".$_GET['order_limit_id']."' and r.customer_id = o.customer_id");
    echo json_encode($g_o->rows);
}
```

And I am getting the output as

```
(new String("[{\"return_id\":\"129\",\"order_id\":\"126450\",\"parent_status\":\"0\"}]"))
```

I want output as array not string .

Can anyone give me the solution for this

Comment: what happens if you just call `alert(data)`?

Comment: it displays as like this "[{\"return_id\":\"129\",\"order_id\":\"126450\",\"parent_status\":\"0\"}]" but it is also string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use JSON , the server should return JSON array and the jquery should parse this json not string see:
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

and also the  jquery should be

```
$.getJSON("URL",function(msg){
     alert("result : "+msg);
});
```

Comment: It works thanks. And also i have another doubt
If i use the $.ajax(); I am getting output as string what i had it before .

Comment: Plz take care to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct jQuery to parse the response as JSON by passing the string 'json' as the third parameter to the `$.get` function:

```
$.get('ajax/order_details.php?order_limit=true&order_limit_id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>', function(data){
  alert(data.toSource());
}, 'json');
```

If you are wanting to use jQuery's lower-level `$ajax` function, you can use the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajax/order_details.php,
  data: {order_limit: true, order_limit_id: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>},
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

This effectively does the same thing as the call to `$.get`. Remember that the $.get method is just a shorthand for the $.ajax method. See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) on `$.get`.

Comment: It works . Also i want the solution for $.ajax(); . I am getting string as output for this also . can u give me the solution for this